# Rendering form via Ajax - Symfony 5

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, symfony5

Up to Symfony 4, I used to load a form, via Ajax, returning something like this:

```
$result = $this->renderView('my/template.html.twig',[
    'form' => $form->createView()
]);
return new Response($result);
```

Since Symfony 5, this is not working anymore. I tried every posible combination using `$this->renderForm()`, `$this->render()` and `'form'=>$form`, with no success. What's the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
return new JsonResponse(['view' => $this->render('path/to_view.html.twig')->getContent()]);
```

It will return a json response to your Ajax call. You can access to 'view' key (name it as you want) which contain the html content of the page rendering [`$this->render()->getContent`]. This is the way I use in my Symfony 5.4 project.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can render form like this

```
public function __invoke()
{
    return $this->render('my/template.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Note:

`render()` -> will return Response object

`renderView()` -> will return string (rendered twig template)